# Добавить аудиосообщение во вложение в вк

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, аудио, long-poll

Имеется сообщество. С сообществом можно переписываться, и пользователю отвечает бот. Пользователь отправил голосовое сообщение, и **сообщество должно ответить** таким же **голосовым сообщением**. Ссылка на аудио файл .ogg или .mp3 есть.

`upload_url = vk.method('docs.getUploadServer', {'type': 'audio_message'})['upload_url']`
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [27] Group authorization failed: method is unavailable with group auth.

Answer (score 0):

docs.getUploadServer - можно вызвать только с ключом доступа пользователя.

Используйте [docs.getMessagesUploadServer](https://vk.com/dev/docs.getMessagesUploadServer)